# JavaFX Controller not linking to JavaFX fxml file

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to create a method in my main screen controller to set a new scene in my program. When attempting to do so, I get the following error:

> Error resolving onAction='#partAddButtonPushed', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.

The relevant fxml code is:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="john.Doe.View_Controller.MainController">
   <children>
        <Button id="addPartsButton" fx:id="partAdd" layoutX="190.0" layoutY="340.0" maxWidth="70.0" minWidth="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#partAddButtonPushed" prefWidth="70.0" text="Add">
```

and the relevant code in the controller is:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML    
    private Button partAdd;

    @FXML
    private void partAddButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent partAddParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/AddPart.fxml"));
        Scene AddPartScene = new Scene (partAddParent);

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(AddPartScene);
        window.show();
    }
```

Would anyone happen to know why they are not linking up?

Comment: The static `load` methods do not work well. Try creating a new FXMLLoader and using it to load it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I do not believe there is an issue with the code that handles the onclick mouse event. The issue is that the button in the fxml file is not properly linked to the button handler and I am not sure why.

Comment: Then it looks correct to me. I would guess, without checking, that it is the `throws IOException`. Try catching and re-throwning as a `RuntimeException` if you can not handle it in the method.

Comment: Check your imports. Make sure you imported `javafx.event.ActionEvent` and not, for instance, `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`.

Comment: @Slaw That's exactly what was off. Thank you so so so so much!